# To-Recipient Required in Email?

Tags: email, smtp, smtp-headers, rfc

I would like to know if a "To"-Recipient is required in an e-mail per definition or if all recipients could be Bcc or Cc.

RFC5322 states

> The only required header fields are the origination date field and
>      the originator address field(s).  All other header fields are
>      syntactically optional.

but what about the SMTP RCPT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All recipients are described using the `RCPT TO:` SMTP verb; the fact that they are to be treated as "To", "Cc" or "Bcc" is only due to the message headers, which are part of the `DATA` portion of the SMTP conversation.

From the MTA's point of view, there is no difference at all: they are all recipients which must receive a copy of the message.

Comment: Bottom line is, there is no requirement of a "To"-Recipient per RFC, correct?

Comment: There's no requirement at all for *any* recipient in the message headers.